# Map reduce: Worst Case

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I'm looking for something to find a vulnerability in the framework,so I'm thinking about how to bring the framework in a state of error or exacerbate the CPU usage . So I try Something You Do This. Have you any suggestions?

Is there a worst use case of MapReduce framework ?
If the answer is yes I would like some examples,
Thank you all.

Comment: Please consider rewording the question to be clearer.

Comment: You should make your clarifications as edits to the original question, not as answers.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected immediately

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want a worst case. However, if you want to stress test or benchmark your cluster, terasort is good starting point.